# Android Emulators Missing SMS Application

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I've recently downloaded Android Studio to my macbook pro and have begun trying to build a messaging based application.  Unfortunately, every emulator I try to run doesn't have an SMS messaging app installed.

I've tried a number of the Nexus emulators with no luck.  I've also tried sending SMS messages to the emulator via telnet, but they're never received.

Is there something that needs to be set up in the emulator definition to allow the app to be loaded with the emulator?

As an example, the current emulator I'm trying is:
Galaxy Nexus 4.65" screen running marshmallow on x86 architecture. I've given it 1.5gb of RAM, 512MB VM heap, and 200MB of internal storage.

EDIT: The logs also show that SMS permissions aren't recognized.  com.example.android.apis isn't able to be granted read/write permission as it doesn't recognize the android.permission.SEND_SMS/RECEIVE_SMS/WRITE_SMS/READ_SMS.